# Encoding: object has no 'CallingApplicationName' property

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP call using PHP and get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'CallingApplicationName' property in /path/to/dev/send.php:95 Stack trace: #0 /path/to/dev/send.php(95): SoapClient->__call('createDeliveryC...', Array) #1 /path/to/dev/send.php(95): SoapClient->createDeliveryCollOrderFwdr(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /path/to/dev/send.php on line 95

Does this error relate to something generic or is it something related to the specific WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the input parameters. I was missing the CallingApplicationName element.